# python 3 - getpass.getpass() is echoing password... nothing seems to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, getpass

So I wrote a script, and it actually worked for a while. I import the getpass module, and sure enough the user name was echoed, but the password was not. I ran the script several weeks later, and now the password is echoing. Here's my code:

```
import getpass

def get_login():
    """get un/pw cerdentials for server"""
    username = input("Username: ")
    password = getpass.getpass()

    return username, password

def some_other_function():
    (username, password) = get_login()
```

When I run the script i get a message "Warning: Password input may be echoed." and sure enough, it's echoed.

I have tried slightly different things such as defining the promt and stream (prompt='Password: ', stream=None)

Thanks

Comment: `getpass.getpass` _attempts_ to turn echo off on your terminal. If it can't do that, it issues a warning. See [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html)

Comment: So where are you running the script? In the console of your IDE perhaps?

Comment: I am using VScode. I tried it on pythons IDLE and it worked fine... Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Something must have changed in my visual studio code setup.