# Python - GetPass Visual Studio Warning: Password Input May be Echoed

Tags: python

The code below is a password program that hides your input. It works on repl.it, an online compiler, but not on Visual Studio. The warning states: GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal. Warning - Password input may be echoed.

```
import getpass

password= getpass.getpass("Enter Password ")
correctPassword= 'Lucas'

while password != correctPassword:
    password = getpass.getpass("Enter Password Again ")

print("Success")
```

I am not sure why this is coming up. Is there anyway I can hide password input?

Comment: [Duplicates this post][1]
  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52952229/python-3-getpass-getpass-is-echoing-password-nothing-seems-to-work?noredirect=1&lq=1